# Proof for three independent events such that $P(A \cup B\cup C)=1$

Tags: probability

Prove that for independent events $A,B,C$ such that $P(A \cup B\cup C)=1$ we have $P(A)=1 \quad or \quad P(B)=1 \quad or \quad P(C)=1$.

Comment: Hint: show that the three complementary events are also independent among each other, and apply the definition of independence.

Comment: I was thinking about using $$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$ but I have no idea where and how can I use complementary events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- First, show that if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $A$ and $B^c$ are also independent.
- Prove that $A^c$, $B^c$ and $C^c$ are independent.
- Combine $0 = 1 - P(A \cup B \cup C) = P((A \cup B \cup C)^c) = P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c)$ with the independence condition.
- Observe that $\alpha_1 \cdot \alpha_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot \alpha_n = 0$, then there exists $k$ such that $\alpha_k = 0$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$